# Django model does not recognize MarkdownxFormField field

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-packages, django-markdownx

I am trying to add `markdownx` support to my model, which will enable preview editing from the admin panel. However, once i change my `content` field from `models.FileField` to `MarkdownXFromField()` django just deletes the content field when migrating and ignores it as if it wasn't part of the model at all.

I've followed [these docs](https://neutronx.github.io/django-markdownx/installation/) exactly but it's not working.

I have also ran `collectstatic`.

```py
# models.py

from os.path import splitext
from uuid import uuid4
from django.db import models
from markdownx.fields import MarkdownxFormField

def hashImageFilename(instance, name):
    ext = splitext(name)[1]
    return "images/{}{}".format(uuid4(), ext)


class Article(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(("title"), max_length=100)
    content = MarkdownxFormField()
    description = models.TextField(("description"), default='')
    uploadDate = models.DateTimeField(("uploadDate"), auto_now=True)
    lastModified = models.DateTimeField(("uploadDate"), auto_now=True)
    publicationDate = models.DateField("publicationDate")
    image = models.ImageField("image", upload_to=hashImageFilename)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

```py
# urls.py

from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from django.conf.urls import url
from django.conf import settings
from markdownx import urls as markdownx

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('api-auth/', include('rest_framework.urls')),
    path('api/articles/', include('articles.api.urls')),
    url(r'^markdownx/', include('markdownx.urls')),
] + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

```py
# admin.py

from django.contrib import admin

# Register your models here.
from markdownx.admin import MarkdownxModelAdmin
from .models import Article

admin.site.register(Article, MarkdownxModelAdmin)
```

```py
# settings.py

INSTALLED_APPS = [
  #...
  'markdownx'
]
```

Comment: That is a `FormField`, not a modelfield.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are confusing the `MarkdownxFormField` *form* field with the `MarkdownxField` model field. You should rewrite the model to:

```
# models.py

from os.path import splitext
from uuid import uuid4
from django.db import models
from markdownx.models import MarkdownxField

def hashImageFilename(instance, name):
    ext = splitext(name)[1]
    return "images/{}{}".format(uuid4(), ext)


class Article(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(("title"), max_length=100)
    content = MarkdownxFormField()
    description = models.TextField(("description"), default='')
    uploadDate = models.DateTimeField(("uploadDate"), auto_now=True)
    lastModified = models.DateTimeField(("uploadDate"), auto_now=True)
    publicationDate = models.DateField("publicationDate")
    image = models.ImageField("image", upload_to=hashImageFilename)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

The `MarkdownxFormField` is used for *forms*, it will thus render with a specific widget, etc. In order to store content in the database, you need a model *field*.

Comment: Oh dear. Yeah that one's on me :-/

Comment: @aviya.developer: relax, personally I think it might have been better to name form/model fields something else than "field", since now it introduces a lot of confusion.